# Ben Sorer U'moreh - is anyones future doomed?

Tags: sources-mekorot, children-parenting, trust-neemanut

the Gemara (Sanhedrin 71a) writes that a Ben Sorer U'moreh never took place. I would like to suggest that the Gemoro is teaching us that it never happened that a Jewish child - however bad he may be - is doomed.

I'd be grateful if anyone can recall a source for such an idea.

Comment: Could you please [edit] this to make it clear what you mean? What does "doomed" mean? What is ambiguous about the Gemoro's statement?

Comment: I have seen this in a Breslov pamphlet a while back. I do not recall their source.

Comment: would appreciate if you could rack your brain as to who when and where

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1823

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact the gemara gave two reasons for the opinion that there never was or will be a ben sorer umoreh. One, the opinion that his father and mother must be the same height and have the same voice, seemingly impossible. Two, that it makes no sense to assume any parents would have their son killed for the meat and wine he drank. 
No one is focusing on the child.

So even if someone decides to make a drasha like what you mention, it is definitely not what the gemara intended to teach us.

Comment: As a side point the 'pintele yid' (the little jew deep down in every jews heart) idea that you seem to be working with is explained by the Sfas Emes as meaning the pintele yid is the opportunity for any jew however bad to do tshuva, not that at any moment a horrible person has some good in him. Its a focus on the potential, not the actual.

Comment: @user6591i wasnt discussing why it couldnt happen i was discussing what the torah was trying to teach us if it has no halachic or practical application